# Github notifications - Mail to PR creator

Tags: github

If I raise a Pull request and if I need to be notified by a mail saying --

```
You have created a Pull request for "bla bla" on "so and so" date.
```

On merge - I get a notification

On comment - I get a notification

So my question is...

1. Are there any such settings in github  which sends a mail to PR creator?
2. Can I tag myself in the PR comment ?

Any help !!

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any such settings in github which sends a mail to PR creator?

There's currently no setting in GitHub that makes the platform work in that way. Note: You can send an email to support@github.com to request for such a feature.

> Can I tag myself in the PR comment ?

Yes, you can. But that won't trigger an email sent to your mailbox

However, if what you're after is keeping track of your own activity on GitHub, there may exist another alternative: GitHub exposes atoms feeds for various endpoints. The user is one of them. Register your own feed in a RSS reader and you're done.

- **Syntax:** `https://github.com/{:user}.atom`
- **Sample:** https://github.com/mojombo.atom

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that despite being up for so long, this question hasn't really been meaningfully addressed. Axibase designed a cool little tool which can do exactly what you're describing here: if a PR is raised in one of your repositories you'll be notified via email or third-party messenger service.

By default the rule will fire when anyone raises a PR, but it can be configured to only respond to specific users as that seems to be one of your requests.

[image]

The workflow here describes the underlying mechanics of the tool and this [guide](https://axibase.com/use-cases/integrations/github/pr-notification.html) will take you through the entire set-up. The whole process should only take about 10 minutes from start to finish.

Disclaimer: I've worked for the team that develops ATSD, which is the database at work here.